# PassportJS JWT Strategy with Node and MySQL not working

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm having issues with the authentication part of my app. I keep getting this "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken' of undefined at Object.**" whenever I run my server.js file. It stops me from progressing any further.

Here is my passport.js file

```
const JWTStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJWT;
const User = require('../dbConnection/database.js');
const keys = require('./keys.js');

const opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: keys.secretOrKey,
};

module.exports = passport => {
  passport.use(
    new JWTStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findOne( {id: jwt_payload.id} ).then(user => {
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }
        return done(null, false);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};
```

User Schema

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

// Initiate mysql connection

const connOptions = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'dummypassword',
    database: 'countdown',
    dialect: 'mysql'
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(connOptions);

// Connect sequelize to the database
sequelize.authenticate()
  .then(console.log('Connection has been successfully established'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', err));


// Create user model
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  firstName: {
    field: 'first_name',
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  lastName: {
    field: 'last_name',
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  tableName: 'users'
});

module.exports = User;
```

And also my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const _ = require('lodash');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const passport = require('passport');
const users = require('./routes/api/users.js');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/public'));
app.use(cors());

// Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Routes
app.use('/users', users);

const port = process.env.port || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});
```

I'm so lost as I literally followed a tutorial that walked this through step by step (https://github.com/rishipr/mern-auth) although it was with MongoDB. I originally didn't use sequelize and thought that might be the issue. So I've refactored it to incorporate sequelize but it didn't solve my issue. Googling didn't help either as no one seems to have this specific issue blocking them from running the server.js file (most people I see are having issues when they make an API call).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with line number 2 in passport.js file

```
const ExtractJWT = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJWT;
```

replace with

```
consst ExtractJWT= require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
```

[passport-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-jwt) have a ExtractJwt class/method not ExtractJWT. Remember Javascrit is a case sensative language.

Comment: I knew it would be something silly like this! Thank you so much for your help!